# Combating voltage drop on low voltage distance sensor

Tags: 3.3v

I have a distance measuring sensor unit that I am having some issues with, its a Sharp GP2Y0D815Z0F Digital Distance Sensor [(Datasheet)](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/pololu/gp2y0d815z.pdf) that takes a 2.7-6.2v DC input. When plugged directly into my 3.3v power source (a NodeMCU esp8266) via a 10cm jumper cable the sensor functions perfectly, its LED (& *out* signal) turning on when there is a part in the way.

However when I use a longer cable (For example a 5m multicore cable or a just two  10cm jumpers) I get a lot of false detection signals (easily seen as the LED flickering). It is worse with the longer cable.

I have tried powering the sensor on the short jumpers and the just sending the signal through the long cable which works fine so I belive it isnt a noise issue. I have tried using a lab-pack to power the source through the long cable and with any voltage of less that 6v i get the noise so I'm led to the conclusion that the voltage just isn't great enough from the esp8266. Unfortunately 5v from a USB port doesn't seem to be enough to prevent errors.

Does my conclusion make sense? Can anyone suggest a easy way to power the sensor? I have a usb port and a 12v power supply next to the esp8266 - this is part of a Home Automation project but I don't easily have any more 240vAC sockets. I'm considering using a voltage divider to convert my 12v to 6v but as the 12v is used elsewhere to power LEDs i'd rather not need to.

Failing all that if anyone can suggest a good short range presence sensor that will work with a esp8266 that would be great.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Given the 4 inches (10cm) wires cause a problem, I suspect you need bypass capacitors, right at the Sensor Module.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: with the 10cm wires the are **no** problems, its only longer lengths that cause problems - occasionally with 20cm, nearly constantly with 5m multi-core

Answer (score 1):

This module does not work by itself, it needs external components around it like a resistor to set LED current and bypass capacitors. How you have mounted the module, is it on ready-made PCB?

The module will draw 70mA current pulses when operating, do you know if you have 70mA available? Do you know if drawing 70mA pulses from the existing 3V3 supply will upset the supply regulator?

Long wires will have resistive voltage drop but also inductance might be a problem due to the pulsed current, which is why you should have the suggested bypass capacitors at the distance sensor pins. Perhaps add a larger bulk capacitor as well, even a 100uF capacitor would not be overkill.